# nginx + uwsgi: -- unavailable modifier requested: 0 --

Tags: nginx, uwsgi, ubuntu-12.04

Ubuntu 12.04, nginx 1.2.0, uwsgi 1.0.3.

I start uwsgi with the following command:

```
uwsgi -s 127.0.0.1:9010 -M -t 30 -A 4 -p 4 -d /var/log/uwsgi.log
```

On each request nginx replies with 502 and uwsgi writes to log the following line:

```
-- unavailable modifier requested: 0 --
```

Comment: On Ubuntu uwsgi is started as a service: `service uwsgi start`.

Answer (score 116):

**Original answer**

For **Python 2** on Ubuntu 11.10, using `upstart`, install the python plugin for `uWSGI` with `apt-get install uwsgi-plugin-python` and if you're using an ini file to configure your `uWSGI` app, then add `plugins = python` to the `[uwsgi]` section and it should solve this problem.

**Edit: Updated for Python 3 and Ubuntu 17.10**

For **Python 3** on Ubuntu 17.10, using `systemd`, install the python plugin for `uWSGI` with `apt-get install uwsgi-plugin-python3` and if you're using an ini file to configure your `uWSGI` app, then add `plugins = python3` to the `[uwsgi]` section and it should solve this problem.

For further information on getting started with `python`/`uWSGI` apps, including how to configure them using an `ini` file then please take a look at this handy [guide](https://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/WSGIquickstart.html)

Comment: The equivalent of this (yum plugin install + uwsgi config change) just worked for me on CentOS7.

Comment: Have been breaking my head, unable to fix this issue. Thank you !

Comment: What about alpine linux?

Comment: I don't know where the file is for the "individual uwsgi app config". Could you be more specific? Is this my uwsgi app's ini file? The /etc/something file? Maybe paste a sample of what the file contents look like so I know what you are referring to? And a typical location for the file?

Comment: It's been quite a while since I had to worry about this (7 years in fact) but I do indeed mean the `uwsgi` app's ini file. As you can probably imagine, I no longer have any config files lying around but a quick google search produced this (seemingly) handy [guide](https://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/WSGIquickstart.html). As for the location of the ini file, it could realistically live almost anywhere. If you were feeling particularly adventurous you could even serve up that ini file from another web server anywhere in the world, like so: `uwsgi --ini http://uwsgi.it/configs/myapp.ini`

Comment: Note that the plugin depends on the versions in `/usr/lib64/uwsgi` (for example), and on a centos box of mine I had to use `plugins = python36`.

Comment: For Python 3, I had to do `plugins = python3`

Answer (score 29):

Solved by installing `uwsgi-plugin-python3` plugin and adding `--plugin python3` option to `uwsgi` start command

Comment: Please write wide answer with more details and set question as resolved with @SHaKie answer

Answer (score 15):

Im starting uwsgi from upstart on Ubuntu. I solved the problem by running `apt-get install uwsgi-plugin-python`, and then adding `plugins=python` to my application.ini in /etc/uwsgi/applications-available.

Answer (score 8):

from http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/ThingsToKnow.html, "To route requests to a specific plugin, the webserver needs to pass a magic number known as a modifier to the uWSGI instances. By default this number is set to 0, which is mapped to Python."

I'm using 9 for a bash script and it's working. the numbers and their meanings are on this page: http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/Protocol.html

in my nginx configuration:

```
location ~ .cgi$ {
    include uwsgi_params;
    uwsgi_modifier1 9;
    uwsgi_pass 127.0.0.1:3031;
}
```

Answer (score 8):

Modify your ini file by added plugins line.

```
    [uwsgi]
    plugins         = python3
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm using Ubuntu 18.04 with Python 3. Below is the exact config I used to get it working.

You must have the Python 3 uWSGI plugin installed:

```
apt install uwsgi-plugin-python3
```

Your Nginx site configuration should point to your uWSGI socket. Make sure the port matches the configuration in the later steps.

```
    location / {
        uwsgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9090;
        include uwsgi_params;
    }
```

Reload the Nginx config to reflect the changes you just made:

```
systemctl reload nginx
```

You can use command-line arguments or an ini file for configuration. I created `uwsgi.ini`. Make sure the socket address matches your nginx config.

```
[uwsgi]
socket = 127.0.0.1:9090
chdir = /var/www
processes = 4
threads = 2
plugins = python3
wsgi-file = /var/www/app.py
```

My app.py just has a basic example:

```
def application(env, start_response):
    start_response('200 OK', [('Content-Type','text/plain')])
    return [b"Hello World!"]
```

Now start the uWSGI server from the command line:

```
uwsgi uwsgi.ini
```